# Liability for property upkeep during inheritance

Tags: real-estate

Assuming a property was awarded by a general judgment from an inheritance estate, and assuming that the actual transfer of said property took several months from the time of the judgement, is there a clearly defined law or precedent concerning who would be responsible for the financial upkeep of said property during that waiting period (the person awarded property or the manager of the estate)?